# Why is Java's HashTable synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, hashtable

What was the driving factor or design plan in making the methods of HashTable synchronized?

This [link](http://www.easywayserver.com/java/why-hashtable-in-java-synchronized/) says that HashTable is synchronized because its methods are synchronized. But, I want to know the reason "why" the methods were synchronized?

Was it just to provide some synchronization feature? A developer could explicitly handle a race condition through synchronization techniques. Why provide HashTable with this feature?

Comment: It is much better to use modern HashMap classes rather that HashTable. Check `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`, `java.util.Collections.synchronizedMap` and so on... HashTable is old and slow.

Comment: Java does not have a standard type named `HashTable`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep in mind: these classes were created "ages" ago - when you check the javadoc for [Hashtable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html), you find it says "since Java 1.0"; whereas HashMap says "1.2"!

Back then, Java was trying to compete with languages like C and C++; by providing unique selling points such as "built-in concurrency".

But people quickly figured that one better synchronizes containers when using them in multi-threaded environments!

So my (more of an opinion-based) answer is: at the time when this class was first designed, people assumed that the requirement "can be used by multiple threads" was more important than "gives optimal performance".

Because Java was "advertised" like: "use it to write multi-threaded write once run everywhere code". That approach fails quickly when the default container classes given to people need additional outside wrapping to actually make them "multi-threaded" ready.

During the years, the people behind Java started to understand that "more granular" solutions are required. Therefore the core collection classes are not synchronized to avoid the corresponding performance hits. Meaning: the default with collections is to go "unprotected"; so you have to put in some thoughts when your requirements is that "multi-threaded" correctness.

Same for "lists" btw: Vector is synchronized; ArrayList is not.

Comment: "[W]hen you check the javadoc for HashTable, you find it" does not exist!

Comment: Correct, it reads Hashtable, not HashTable; I updated the answer and added javadoc link too.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot tell you why. Those who designed Java over two decades ago maybe can. It's not a useful question. Assuming you actually wanted to ask about `java.util.Hashtable` and not the fictional `HashTable` type, bear in mind that it's been obsolescent for nineteen years. Nineteen years! Don't use it. It (and `Vector`) have cruft that the replacement types, both synchronized and unsynchronized, do not carry. Use the modern (as of nineteen years ago) types.